# how to add bing spell check code to virtual assistant

Tags: azure, chatbot, spell-checking

I have a functional virtual assistant, and a provisioned spell check key.   When I enable spell check in luis, I am asked to add my key to the url, which works.  however, when working through the VA in virtual assistant, I need to add the spell check key somewhere.  Presumably in appsettings or cognitivemodels json.   I can't find any documentation on this.   Help?

Comment: But my suggestion will be save it in code behind and take the text which you want check spell and pass it to your backed code as input parameter. It would be best practice I guess rather adding at VA

Comment: Agree possible, but LUIS has an option to automate spellcheck - so validating it prior to sending to LUIS would be redundant if properly implemented.   I assume somewhere in the VA dialog there is a URL passed to the API that needs to include the Spell Check Key, perhaps?

Comment: Could you please share your code snippet whatever you have tried so far.

Comment: this is actually -exactly- my question.   where to put the code.   Activating spell check in luis tells me to add the key to the url calling luis.   I can't find this in Azure Virtual Assistant anywhere.  Maybe not a question about the code required - more a question about virtual assistant configuration?